# Spring cannot include/exclude beans using filters of type REGEX with an asterisk in @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, component-scan

I am trying to manage the beans my spring application loads using IncludeFilters property of `@ComponentScan` annotation. I use filter of type `FilterType.REGEX`. I would like to match anything as the last part of my pattern using but I seems not to work that way at all. 
I have a bean definitions:

```java
package org.example.child;

public class ChildDao {}
...
public class ChildService{}
...
public class ChildComponent{}
```

and configuration class definition:

```java
@ComponentScan(
        value = "com.example", 
        includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, 
                pattern = "com.example.*.Child*")})
```

With such a configuration, Spring does not find any bean at all.

When asterisk is used to match not the very last part of the pattern but is used somewhere in between, then it seems to work without a problem.

For example, following configuration matches all the Services without a problem:

```java
@ComponentScan(
        value = "com.example", 
        includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, 
                pattern = "com.example.*.*Service")})
```

**Is this a designed behaviour of the framework or should it be possible to match the last part of the pattern using such an 'ant like' regex pattern?**

Comment: so you want to match all classes that starts with `Child` in this `org.example.child` package am i right?

Comment: what do you mean `Spring does not find any bean at all.`?

Comment: Yes, I want to watch all the classes in org.example.child package which names start with Child. With a pattern `Child*` spring does not find any of the mentioned beans ChildDao, ChildService or ChildComponent. I think that I misunderstood how IncludeFilters work. I expected it to match ant-like patterns like `Child*`, but it uses standard java pattern and matcher machanism. The only reason why the second example works is because it includes `.*Service` pattern, which matches the preceding part of the name. I think that pattern like `Child.*` would work in this case.

Comment: your code works for me and i'm not sure why it is not working, try with square brackets `[Child]*`

Comment: Unfortunately brackets don't work for me. I'm not sure if it should work, as square brackets are used in regex to match any character mentioned in it, so I think `[Child]*` would match only the pattern consisting ot those characters.

Comment: how are you testing it? can you please upload it to git repo?

Comment: I forgot to add that it is also important to set `useDefaultFilters = false` in `@ComponentScan` to reproduce it. I create small example project to show you what I mean - just run junit in src directory - one uses correct format, the second one uses the incorrect format from the question. You can find it here : https://github.com/CaptainAye/include-filters-example

Comment: I added also a test which shows why `[Child]*` is not correct. Although it matches classes from `com.example.child` package, it basically matches any class in `com.example*` packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters of type `FilterType.REGEX` are matched using standard java `Pattern` and `Matcher`, so no ant-like patterns like `"com.example.*.Child*"` would match. The only reason why `"com.example.*.*Service"` is because of the `.*` which matches any sequence of characters. In order to include/exlude using regex use valid regex.

Edit:

So in this case, one possible option would be to use pattern like `com.example.child.Child.*` to match any classes from `com.example.child` package starting with the Child in their names.

Comment: This is not right answer your code works for me and also try my comment